# Attaching metadata to Properties of objects you can't change?

Tags: c#, data-structures

For a given Dictionary(string to object) that can contain primitive data types as well a complex class data types, there is a need to be able to add additional information for some of the Properties(may be nested) without changing the existent data structures in the dictionary and be able to get this metadata per Property for later use. 
In addition this metadata should be persisted for later use and not only in run-time so using a references is problematic.

The solution I have tried is to save additional metadata KeyValuePair in the dictionary. For example to define the Street Property of the Address of the Data object as special and important the following information will be added

```
{ "root.Data.Address.Street", new Dictionary<string, object>()
            {
                { "special", true },
                { "important", true }
            }}
```

to query for the metadata information for the Property we will search for the path of this Property in the root of the dictionary.

An example case:

```
//The data in the dictionary can't be changed or wrapped in some way
Dictionary<string, object> dataObject = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "Name", "name123"},
            { "Addresses", new List<Address>()
                {
                    new Address("A", "B", 1),
                    new Address("C", "D", 2)
                }
            },
            {"Data", new Data("123Name", new Address("E", "F", 3))}
        };

//Can't be changed
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Address Address { get; }

    public Data(string name, Address address)
    {
        Name = name;
        Address = address;
    }
}

//Can't be changed
public class Address
{
    public string City { get; }
    public string Street { get; }
    public int Number { get; }

    public Address(string city, string street, int number)
    {
        City = city;
        Street = street;
        Number = number;
    }
}
```

The expected behavior is to be able to query the data as close to the following as possible:

```
dataObject["Data"].Address.Street.special == true
dataObject["Data"].Address.City.important == false
```

Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Make the City and Street properties are complex types, that contain such properties as Value, Special, Important, etc.

Comment: Make a wrapper or decorator class in which the City and Street properties are complex types. Make mapper to the Address class. Make implicit cast operator.